# WPF How to create a Custom Textbox with validation and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I'm developing a custom text box for currency editing.
I've seen some ready to use ones, but they're complicated and/or not really usable, forcing you to bad practices (such as hard coding the name that's supposed to be used on the control).
So I've decided to do it myself, but I'm having trouble to work with the binding options, since the property assigned to the binding attribute must be a decimal, but the Text property of the TextBox control accepts strings.
The answer I thought was, maybe, override the access methods (getters and setters) to the Text property in the base class (TextBox), but it is not allowed.
My binding should be set to the value, that sets the text property of the TextBox formatting it as text (with the currency symbols and everything) on the go, but converting it back to a numeric datatype on the Get method.
This is what I've achieved so far:

```
public class CurrencyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private bool IsValidKey(Key key)
        {
            int k = (int)key;
            return ((k >= 34 && k <= 43) //digits 0 to 9
                || (k >= 74 && k <= 83) //numeric keypad 0 to 9
                || (k == 2) //back space
                || (k == 32) //delete
                );
        }
        private void Format()
        {
            //formatting decimal to currency text here
            //Done! no problems here
        }
        private void FormatBack()
        {
            //formatting currency text to decimal here
            //Done! no problems here
        }
        private void ValueChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Format();
        }
        private void MouseClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Format();
            // Prevent changing the caret index
            this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        private void MouseReleased(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Format();
            // Prevent changing the caret index
            this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValidKey(e.Key))
                e.Handled = true;
            if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.None)
                return;
            this.Format();
        }
        private void PastingEventHandler(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
        {
            // Prevent copy/paste
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            // Disable copy/paste
            DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(this, PastingEventHandler);
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, PastingEventHandler);
            this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;
            this.PreviewKeyUp += KeyPressed;
            this.PreviewMouseDown += MouseClicked;
            this.PreviewMouseUp += MouseReleased;
            this.TextChanged += ValueChanged;
            this.Format();
        }
    }
```

and this is the XAML:

```
<MyNamespace:CurrencyTextBox x:Name="TxbCurrency" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Element.Currency, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

So far so good! The binding from the decimal property to the TextBox text's is "right on". But how to get the decimal back from the text after it's editing is now the problem.
The binding from decimal to the .Text uses boxing to hide the ToString() method.
**Question here:**
How can I overload the Parse() method from decimal in this case to use my FormatBack() method to get the decimal from the TextBox's Text?

Comment: i suppose to let the user enter any text even if strings and when lost focus make invoke if he didn't add decimal value

Comment: I guess the question wasn't clear. The problem is with the binding, not with the formatting logic. Formating the text is ok already...

Comment: if this is the case, create new `Dependency Property` call it Value and bind your currency to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create new `Dependency Property` like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         "Value", 
         typeof(decimal?),
         typeof(CurrencyTextBox),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                     new decimal?(), 
                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                     new PropertyChangedCallback(ValuePropertyChanged)));

private static void ValuePropertyChanged(
                         DependencyObject d,
                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrencyTextBox x = (CurrencyTextBox)d;
    x.Value = (decimal?)e.NewValue;
}
```

and then bind to this new property

Comment: This solved the problem. in the ValuePropertyChanged() I've set the  Value property with FormatBack and voilà! Thumbs up! Can't vote, thou, because of my 'newby' reputation!

Answer (score 7):

Well, for future purposes, if anybody is stuck with the same trouble, here's the complete code for the currency text box. Feel free to use it, modify it, sell it (don't think it's valuable, thou), or play with it as much as you want!

```
/*
 * the necessary usings:
 * using System.Globalization;
 * using System.Windows;
 * using System.Windows.Controls;
 * using System.Windows.Input;
 * using System.Threading;
 * And don't forget to change the currency settings on the XAML
 * or in the defaults (on the contructor)
 * It's set by default to Brazilian Real (R$)
 */
public class CurrencyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CurrencyTextBox()
    {
        CurrencySymbol = "R$ ";
        CurrencyDecimalPlaces = 2;
        DecimalSeparator = ",";
        ThousandSeparator = ".";
        Culture = "pt-BR";
    }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    private int CurrencyDecimalPlaces { get; set; }
    public string DecimalSeparator { get; set; }
    public string ThousandSeparator { get; set; }
    public string Culture { get; set; }
    private bool IsValidKey(int k)
    {
        return (k >= 34 && k <= 43) //digits 0 to 9
            || (k >= 74 && k <= 83) //numeric keypad 0 to 9
            || (k == 2) //back space
            || (k == 32) //delete
            ;
    }
    private string Format(string text)
    {
        string unformatedString = text == string.Empty ? "0,00" : text; //Initial state is always string.empty
        unformatedString = unformatedString.Replace(CurrencySymbol, ""); //Remove currency symbol from text
        unformatedString = unformatedString.Replace(DecimalSeparator, ""); //Remove separators (decimal)
        unformatedString = unformatedString.Replace(ThousandSeparator, ""); //Remove separators (thousands)
        decimal number = decimal.Parse(unformatedString) / (decimal)Math.Pow(10, CurrencyDecimalPlaces); //The value will have 'x' decimal places, so divide it by 10^x
        unformatedString = number.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Culture));
        return unformatedString;
    }
    private decimal FormatBack(string text)
    {
        string unformatedString = text == string.Empty ? "0.00" : text;
        unformatedString = unformatedString.Replace(CurrencySymbol, ""); //Remove currency symbol from text
        unformatedString = unformatedString.Replace(ThousandSeparator, ""); //Remove separators (thousands);
        CultureInfo current = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture; //Let's change the culture to avoid "Input string was in an incorrect format"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Culture);
        decimal returnValue = decimal.Parse(unformatedString);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = current; //And now change it back, cuz we don't own the world, right?
        return returnValue;
    }
    private void ValueChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Keep the caret at the end
        this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;
    }
    private void MouseClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Prevent changing the caret index
        e.Handled = true;
        this.Focus();
    }
    private void MouseReleased(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Prevent changing the caret index
        e.Handled = true;
        this.Focus();
    }
    private void KeyReleased(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = Format(this.Text);
        this.Value = FormatBack(this.Text);
    }
    private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidKey((int)e.Key))
            return;
        e.Handled = true;
        this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;
    }
    private void PastingEventHandler(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
    {
        // Prevent/disable paste
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(this, PastingEventHandler);
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, PastingEventHandler);
        this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;
        this.KeyDown += KeyPressed;
        this.KeyUp += KeyReleased;
        this.PreviewMouseDown += MouseClicked;
        this.PreviewMouseUp += MouseReleased;
        this.TextChanged += ValueChanged;
        this.Text = Format(string.Empty);
    }
    public decimal? Value
    {
        get { return (decimal?)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(decimal?),
        typeof(CurrencyTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new decimal?(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValuePropertyChanged)));
    private static void ValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CurrencyTextBox)d).Value = ((CurrencyTextBox)d).FormatBack(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<myNamespace:CurrencyTextBox
    Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyDecimalProperty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    CurrencySymbol="R$ "
    Culture="pt-BR"
    CurrencyDecimalPlaces="2"
    DecimalSeparator=","
    ThousandSeparator="." />
```

Comment: Wow, that really helped! I got another problem here still: When I put this Control onto my WPF UI, the initial Value I bound to does not show until I explicitly tell the control to update.

Is there a way to implement that into your Code?

EDIT: 
I added the following into the Setter of Value:
`if(!this.IsFocused)
                    this.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", value)`

Comment: Why add event-handlers instead of just overriding the base handlers? Instead of "private void KeyReleased(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)", why not "protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)"?

Answer (score 0):

take look on this article i think it will help you.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation

or you can put this

```
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+"); //regex that matches disallowed text
    return !regex.IsMatch(text);
}
```

and in `PreviewTextInput` event put this

> e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually possible, except for the simple case of a box that only allows digits. Ideally you'd like a box that can only contain a valid entry, but decimals contain some characters (like '-' and '.') that are not valid on their own. The user can't start by typing a '-' without putting the box into an invalid state.

Similarly they could enter '1.', and then delete the 1 and leave the box in an indeterminate state. Sure, it causes a validation error and a red border, but your view model still thinks the value is 1, and isn't aware of the problem.

For positive integers, you can only allow digits and automatically insert a zero when blank (although that's a little unfriendly)

For decimals and negative integers, I think the best you can do is to constrain the keys a user can type, but you still need to wrap your number property in a string and validate it - either when the OK button is pressed, or ideally implement INotifyDataError to display the error and disable the OK button.