# C# - WPF - Prevent an update of a bound focused TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a TextBox in a Windows Desktop WPF application bound to a property of a ViewModel. Now the user focuses the TextBox and starts entering a new value. During this time a background process gets a new Value for the same Property (e.g. because another user in a multi user environment enters a new value and an observer is detecting and propagating this change) and calls a PropertyChanged event for this Property. Now the value changes and the stuff the current user just entered is lost.

Is there a built in way to prevent the change while the TextBox is focused? Or do I have to build my own solution?

Comment: Well if you want an ugly fix you can use javascript/jQuery to override the eventListener correct?

Comment: @yardpenalty - The question is for C# and WPF

Comment: Right but .NET/C#  library for WPF creates javascript in the presentation layer of the framework in some circumstances (yours) so the way you asked the question was like you needed a quick fix.

Comment: @yardpenalty - OK, I updated the question to make it clear that I have a plain Windows Desktop WPF Application...

Comment: NP, I am pretty sure this is exactly what you need to do. Override the default behavior. Do a little refactoring in debug if needed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27973861/1870110

Comment: @yardpenalty - sorry, no, because creating a new Dependency Property and binding to this Property is causing the same problem. If the New Property is changed from a background thread while editing the same problem occurs.

Comment: It's a race condition anyway. You might want to disable the TextBox like `IsEnabled="{Binding IsServiceWorking}"` when the service is updating the property.

Comment: This question seems too broad to me. You could suppress updating of the view model property from the background task if the `TextBox` has focus, but it still leaves open the question of which property value should take precedence. I.e. if and when the local user moves focus, should their new value then override the value set by the remote user, or is there some other prioritization you want to use? And of course without a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, there's an even greater number of possible answers. Please narrow the question and include an appropriate code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a custom control is needed to achieve the behavior you describe. By overriding a couple methods on the default WPF TextBox, we can keep the user input even if the View Model changes.

The `OnTextChanged` method will be called regardless of how our textbox is updated (both for keyboard events and View Model changes), but overriding the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method will separate out direct user-input. However, `OnPreviewKeyDown` does not provide easy access to the textbox value because it is also called for non-printable control characters (arrow keys, backspace, etc.)

Below, I made a WPF control that inherits from TextBox and overrides the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method to capture the exact time of the last user key-press. `OnTextChanged` checks the time and updates the text only if both events happen in quick succession.

If the last keyboard event was more than a few milliseconds ago, then the update probably did not happen from our user.

```
public class StickyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private string _lastText = string.Empty;
    private long _ticksAtLastKeyDown;

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _ticksAtLastKeyDown = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsInitialized)
            _lastText = Text;

        if (IsFocused)
        {
            var elapsed = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - _ticksAtLastKeyDown);

            // If the time between the last keydown event and our text change is
            // very short, we can be fairly certain than text change was caused
            // by the user.  We update the _lastText to store their new user input
            if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= 5) {
                _lastText = Text;
            }
            else {
                // if our last keydown event was more than a few seconds ago,
                // it was probably an external change
                Text = _lastText;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Here's a sample View Model which I used for testing. It updates its own property 5 times from a separate thread every 10 seconds to simulate a background update from another user.

```
class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private delegate void UpdateText(ViewModelMain vm);
    private string _textProperty;

    public string TextProperty
    {
        get { return _textProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_textProperty != value)
            {
                _textProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        TextProperty = "Type here";

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var sleep = 10000 * i;

            var copy = i;
            var updateTextDelegate = new UpdateText(vm =>
                vm.TextProperty = string.Format("New Value #{0}", copy));
            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                updateTextDelegate.Invoke(this);
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This XAML creates our custom `StickyTextBox` and a regular `TextBox` bound to the same property to demonstrate the difference in behavior:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding TextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5"/>
  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" Text="The 'sticky' text box">
    <local:StickyTextBox Text="{Binding TextProperty}" MinWidth="200" />
  </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!