# WPF: How to reuse XAML Fragment?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to reuse an XAML fragment with substitution strings as parameters.

sort of like a #define with some function style arguments.

Can I do this?

If so, how is the best way to go around doing it?

So, here's invalid XAML of what I want to do

```
<Template Base="TextBox" key="ValidatedTextBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="{SomeAttributeName}">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:SomeRule></local:SomeRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</Template>
```

...
and then elsewhere in XAML, instead of using a TextBox, I'd do

```
<ValidatedTextBox SomeAttributeName="MyPropertyToBeBound" AttributeNotOnTemplate="Value">
    <ElementNotOnTemplate />
</ValidatedTextBox>
```

In particular, I want to be able to customize instances of this template.

I'm happy to read docs, but I don't know what to search for to find appropriate docs that aren't hilariously complicated for essentially a find-and-replace mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're just trying to add validation to a `TextBox` or create a custom control. If you're struggling with the validation this [post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) gives a very nice overview. In summary, you can do something like this

```
public class ViewModel : System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        /* Set default age */
        this.Age = 30;
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Age":
                    if (this.Age < 10 || this.Age > 100)
                        return "The age must be between 10 and 100";
                    break;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

If you'd like to create your own error template you can do it for an individual `TextBox` like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

Alternatively, you can define a style like this

```
<Style TargetType="x:TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you're trying to create a custom control this [post](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973220/wpf-how-to-create-a-custom-textbox-with-validation-and-binding) are worth looking at. The key part is adding a `DependencyProperty` to your control like this

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTextChangedCallback));

private static void OnTextChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Validation in here
}
```

Then you could use it like this

```
<MyTextBox Text="My Text" .../>
```